# how to convert css string into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well here is what I'm trying to do.
I want to convert a array which contains CSS rules like so:

```
[

".divd { bottom: 0px; height: 500px; }"

, 

".divk { font-size: 14px; }"

]
```

I want to turn this into:

```
cssarray['divd'] =  {
        bottom: "0px",
        height: "500px",
    };
```

Here is what i've done so far:

```
    var splitSelector= css.split("{");
    var splitProperty = split[1].split(";");
    var v =[];
    for(i in splitProperty ){
        v = $.extend(v,splitProperty[i].split(":"));
    }
```

I have tried to get this work with lot's of split statements but im out of luck.

Comment: Your code is only handling rules for css classes... How would your cssarray look for a div.divd selector? Would it be cssarray['div.divd']? It now has 'divd' as a key which means it ignores the preceding dot in the selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YrQ7B/3/

```
    var arr = [".divd { bottom: 0px; height: 500px; }", 
"#divk { font-size: 14px; }"];

var output = {};
for(var k in arr)
{
    var value = arr[k], key;
    // Get key
    value.replace(/(\.|#)([a-z\s]+){/gi, function($1, $2, $3){
          key = $3;
    });
    // Make object
    output[key] = {};

    // Replace First part
    value = value.replace(/\.([a-z\s]+) {/gi, "");
    value = value.replace("}", "");

    value.replace(/([a-z\-]+)([^:]+)?:([^0-9a-z]+)?([^;]+)/g, function($1, $2, $3, $4, $5){             
        output[key][$2] = $5;
    });
}

console.log(output);
​
​
```

The log:

```
Object
    divd: Object
        bottom: "0px"
        height: "500px"
    divk: Object
        font-size: "14px"
```

Comment: i really thank you for your hard work , much appreciated ...
but the problem is that if the selector was an id selector this wont work :( any how this is great for class selector and does what it should do ... thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately parsing CSS tokens is not exactly as easy as splitting a string, in fact, you ideally will need a parser, and I would suggest the use of an existing CSS parser for your task:

- [JQuery CSS Parser](http://bililite.com/blog/2009/01/16/jquery-css-parser/)
- [JSCSSP](http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

a no-RegExp method

```
var cssObj = {},
    arr = [".divd { bottom: 0px; height: 500px; }", ".divk { font-size: 14px; }"],
    arr_i = arr.length,
    i, j, k, str,
    sel, vals, val;
while(arr_i-- > 0){       // loop over array
    str = arr[arr_i];
    i = str.indexOf('{');
    sel = str.slice(0,i); // get Selector
    vals = str.slice(i+1,str.lastIndexOf('}'));           // get values
    val = vals.slice(0,vals.lastIndexOf(';')).split(';'); // and put in array
    cssObj[sel] = {};
    k = val.length;
    while(k-- > 0){
        j = val[k].indexOf(':');                      // get name-value pair
        cssObj[sel][val[k].slice(0,j).trim()] = val[k].slice(j+1).trim();
    }
}
console.log(cssObj); // see output
```

for use as function, pass `arr` and change `console.log` to `return`. The `.slice(0,vals.lastIndexOf(';'))` assumes you end the last entry before the `}` with a semicolon. If you don't want to assume this, take it out and check last array item isn't blank/whitespace.

[jsperf vs RegExp method](http://jsperf.com/arr-to-css-obj)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past, but only when I knew exactly what I would be sending into the regexp - mainly because I'm sure there will be syntax out there that could break it (especially with the likes of mixins, css animations, css variables, and media queries). It's for these reasons why you should probably follow Mario's answer.

However, it has worked on the majority of my own css files that I've thrown at it and may help others out there... It isn't tailored to work with an array structure like you are using though, but that could be easily changed. Obivously you could optimise things by getting rid of `RegExp` and just using `indexOf` as shhac has done, but I find the expressiveness of RegExp far easier to work with and far easier to extend if and when you need to.

A few notes

1. **It assumes there are no comments in the CSS** - you could always add a replace to strip comments.
2. **It relies on JSON.parse method being available** - you could always include a non JSON fallback.

The code with comments:

```
window.onload = function(){
  /// this is designed to find a <style> element in the page with id="css"
  var entireStylesheetString = document.getElementById('css').innerHTML;
  var css = String('{'+entireStylesheetString+'}')
    /// convert double quotes to single to avoid having to escape
    .replace(/"/gi,"'")
    /// replace all whitespace sequences with single space
    .replace(/\s+/g,' ')
    /// sort the first open brace so things are neat
    .replace(/^{/,'{\n')
    /// sort the newlines so each declaration is on own line
    .replace(/\}/g,'}\n')
    /// find the selectors and wrap them with quotes for JSON keys
    .replace(/\n\s*([^\{]+)\s+?\{/g,'\n"$1":{')
    /// find an attribute and wrap again with JSON key quotes
    .replace(/([\{;])\s*([^:"\s]+)\s*:/g,'$1"$2":')
    /// find values and wrap with JSON value quotes
    .replace(/":\s*([^\}\{;]+)\s*(;|(\}))/g,'":"$1",$3')
    /// add commas after each JSON object
    .replace(/\}/g,'},')
    /// make sure we don't have too many commas
    .replace(/,\s*\}/g,'}');
  /// remove the final end comma
  css = css.substring(0,css.length-2);
  try{
    /// parse using JSON
    console.log(JSON.parse(css));
  }catch(ee){
    console.log(ee);
  }
};
```

The code by it's lonesome:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var entireStylesheetString = document.getElementById('css').innerHTML;
  var css = String('{'+entireStylesheetString+'}')
    .replace(/"/gi,"'")
    .replace(/\s+/g,' ')
    .replace(/^{/,'{\n')
    .replace(/\}/g,'}\n')
    .replace(/\n\s*([^\{]+)\s+?\{/g,'\n"$1":{')
    .replace(/([\{;])\s*([^:"\s]+)\s*:/g,'$1"$2":')
    .replace(/":\s*([^\}\{;]+)\s*(;|(\}))/g,'":"$1",$3')
    .replace(/\}/g,'},')
    .replace(/,\s*\}/g,'}');
  css = css.substring(0,css.length-2);
  try{console.log(JSON.parse(css));}catch(ee){console.log(ee);}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a proponent of eval, but if you convert

.  to ["

first space to "]=

: to :"

; to ",

Then an eval will set the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You might be able simply append a style tag;

```
var data=[".divd { bottom: 0px; height: 500px; }", 
".divk { font-size: 14px; }"
]

var $style=$('<style>');

$.each( data, function(i, item){
  $style.append( item + ';');
})

$('head').append($style)
```