# php - split CSS into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, css, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need some help creating a multi-dimensional array from CSS. For example:

```
$css = "body { font-weight:40px; color:#444; } #wrapper { width: 500px; }";
```

I do have the following code from [Split CSS inside the {} to array of key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461775/split-css-inside-the-to-array-of-key-value-pairs) but this doesn't do the selector aswell

```
function BreakCSS($CSS) {
$results = array();

foreach(explode(';', $CSS) AS $attr)
    if (strlen(trim($attr)) > 0) // for missing semicolon on last element, which is legal
    {
        list($name, $value) = explode(':', $attr);
        $results[trim($name)] = trim($value);
    }
return $results;
```

}

I am not a expert when it comes to this kind of coding. Ideally i would like:

```
array(
    'body' => array (
        array(
            'font-weight',
            '40',
            'px'
        ),
        array(
            'color',
            '#444',
            ''
        )
    )
)
```

Furthermore, is there a way of checking to see if !important has been added to the end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then I have to ask the same thing as they did in the post you're referring to, why not use an already built parser?

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson for your comment. I can see that the parser will clean up the CSS code but what I cant see is where you can create a multi dimensional array as per the output I need. Currently looking at https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Comment: That's just one parser. When I Googled "parse css with php" I found multiple libraries.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE! I have found a solution which someone has modified the code originally added above. [Break a CSS file into an array with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215074/break-a-css-file-into-an-array-with-php)

Not 100% perfect (recommend using a parser) but this works for my quick tests or proof of concept for now.